# Preserve 'randomness' in parallel programs

Tags: random, parallel-processing, numerical-methods

I've always drawn random numbers like,

```
srand(time(NULL))                      // seed with current time
...
double rnum = 1.0*rand()/RAND_MAX;     // convert to [0.0,1.0]
```

And I've never had any issues. I'm currently running parallel code with up to hundreds of cores, and they seem to have the same 'random' series of numbers, presumably because they're all starting at the same time (or very similar times).

**What's a good way to randomize between processors?**

I can access each processor's ID, so I was thinking about using something like,

```
srand(time(NULL)*(pG->my_id+1))        // +1 incase my_id == 0
```

But I don't know exactly how seeding works - so I was a little worried about an integer multiplier (especially a factor of 2?) not being 'random enough' (note: I have no specific criteria for sufficiently random).

Comment: If you are really worried about powers of two, you can build a table of primes and multiply by `primes[processor_ID]`, but I don't think that's any better than your current approach.

Comment: @H2CO3 you mean just a mapping from ID's to a sequence of prime numbers? (e.g. `int primes[4] = { 1, 3, 5, 7 };`)?

Comment: Yes, except that `1` is not a prime number.

Comment: @H2CO3 ha, sure - but it gives me a unique seed - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

All pseudo-random number generators yield sequences of values that eventually cycle.  One abstract viewpoint is that the seed is equivalent to an entry point into the cycle.  **Any** two different seeds represent different entry points, and should be fine as long as the cycle length is sufficiently long that the subsequences don't overlap.  You'd do about as well to pick 10 sequential seed values for 10 processors as to do anything extremely fancy.  For instance, here are 10 values apiece from seeding Ruby's Mersenne twister with 0, 1, and 2.  As you can see, they appear to have nothing to do with each other even though the seeds were picked sequentially.

seed = 0: 
0.5488135039273248
0.7151893663724195
0.6027633760716439
0.5448831829968969
0.4236547993389047
0.6458941130666561
0.4375872112626925
0.8917730007820798
0.9636627605010293
0.3834415188257777

seed = 1: 0.417022004702574
0.7203244934421581
0.00011437481734488664
0.30233257263183977
0.14675589081711304
0.0923385947687978
0.1862602113776709
0.34556072704304774
0.39676747423066994
0.538816734003357

seed = 2: 0.43599490214200376
0.025926231827891333
0.5496624778787091
0.4353223926182769
0.42036780208748903
0.3303348210038741
0.2046486340378425
0.6192709663506637
0.29965467367452314
0.26682727510286663

Comment: Mersenne twister's state is huge and consists of 624 32-bit integers. As the 32-bit seed value is spread over the state space using a special algorithm (see e.g. the pseudo-code for `initialize_generator` in e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_twister#Pseudocode)), seeding it with 0 and with 1 produces well separated states. On the other hand, `rand()` uses a simple congruent PRNG with small state space and is very prone to correlations, therefore - prime numbers as H2CO3 comments.

Comment: @HristoIliev Agreed, but generators with short cycles are at risk of overlapping subsequences pretty much no matter what you do. In fact, many simulation languages in the 1980/90's didn't let you pick the seed, but instead divided the cycle into k equal length subsequences and would only allow you to specify which subsequence you wanted.  That was very limiting when k was something like 8 or 10.  Thank goodness for modern PRNGs. Since I didn't see any mention of a particular language or generator, my working assumption was that zhermes would be using something decent.